# adding a right click to a text box user control in Visual Studio designer?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, events, visual-studio-designer

I have a textbox user control and when I double click, it adds the `Text_Changed` listening method to the code that I can fill in.

How do I get it to add my `Right_Click` listening method or `Left_Click` listening method or `Double_Click` listening method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Visual Studio, all your events are accessible by clicking the lightning icon (Events) at the top of the Properties window.

You can double-click the name of an event to create a new handler, or choose an existing handler from the dropdown.

Answer (score 3):

Right click on the textbox and open the properties window. In the properties, click on the events (as shown in the picture below) and double-click on the `MouseDown` event.

[image]

This will create the method. Then put the following code:

```
private void TextBox1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Right)
    {
        // do something
    }
}
```

For the left click you can use the same method or you can add the `MouceClick` event which fires only on the left button click.

If you need this to change the `ContextMenu` then chek this: [Add ContextMenu to TextBox](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/CSharp/0460__GUI-Windows-Forms/AddContextMenutoTextBox.htm)

Comment: there is no events in my properties for the textbox :( :( so this ended up not working.  How do I get that property to show up?  I only see Cursor, Dock, Enabled, FlowBreak (they are in alphabetical order, right?) and so only "Enabled" starts with "E"...no Events there?

Comment: The events tab Schaliasos is referring to looks like a lightning bolt.

Comment: @DeanHiller I edited my ansewr to be more clear. I thought it whould be easy to found it since when you hover the mouse over it, it displays a tooltip 'Events'